# Enabling CORS with WebApi v1

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

In the past, I was able to get past CORS restrictions in WebApi v1 using the following code in the controller. I don't have the option of upgrading to WebApi 2 and prefer to not use another library, if possible.

Class to annotate controllers:

```
  public class AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (actionExecutedContext.Response != null)
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
  }

  //annotated controller
  [AllowCrossSiteJson]
  public class UserController : ApiController
  {
```

This doesn't work now so I added the following to web.config as suggested in other stackoverflow posts

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

I am still getting the OPTIONS 405 error during the call. I can see the response header expected yet...:

```
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

I'm not sure what else to try.

[UPDATE]
Thanks to @Samuels's suggestion I was able to get past my issue. I took the naive route for now. It is a "naive" solution because it blindly sends a 200 status for all request (of type OPTIONS). A better solution would be to create a message handler. Here's the quick fix for those interested.

```
  [AcceptVerbs("OPTIONS")]
  public HttpResponseMessage OPTIONS()
  {
         var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
         response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
         response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,DELETE");
         response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
         return response;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you're changes are doing are setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. This is one part of CORS, but it has nothing to do with the `OPTIONS` requests. All that header does is instruct the browser that any origin can make requests to your server and read the request. Your application must explicitly handle the `OPTIONS` request. HTTP 405 indicates that your application *isn't* handling that request. A naive way to handle `OPTIONS` requests is to just return HTTP 200 response.

```
[AcceptVerbs("OPTIONS")]
public HttpResponseMessage Options()
{
    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    resp.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    resp.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,DELETE");

    return resp;
}
```

See [this guide](http://www.jefclaes.be/2012/09/supporting-options-verb-in-aspnet-web.html) for supporting `OPTIONS` requests in your controller.